# Rails, using ActiveRecord to find all rows matching a parent row attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a class Foo which has_many Bars. Foo has an attribute, some_id. I want to Retrieve all Bar instances where the Foo has some_id = N. In SQL this translates into something like:

`select * from bar inner join foo on foo.id = bar.foo_id WHERE foo.some_id = N`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like:

`Bar.all :joins => :foo, :conditions => {:foos => {:some_id => N}}`